# How to modify a private access object?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I made a frame and added a desktop pane (dp_1) to it. Then I created a separate internal jframe form (Inj) and assigned this code to a button in frame form (main).

```
Inj inj = new Inj();
dp_1.add(inj);
inj.setVisible(true);
```

It works fine. Then I created another internal jframe form(Inj_1). I want to set it visible by a button in Inj. I did trying the same code, but there comes an error.

Error is ;

```
error: dp_1 has private access in NewJFrame
```

***() include the variable name.**

Comment: *"has private access in NewJFrame"*  Don't extend `JFrame` unless adding new methods or overriding old ones.  Instead keep a reference to one.

Comment: Absolutely right.  I rarely see a good reason to extend classes, especially Swing.  I usually prefer composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide a public method in the class that owns that variable and let it modify its own state.

You can also use reflection if you must, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: But when i add a item like desktop pane, net beans automatically assign it as a private. So that i can,t access them through a code in another class. Even i can't change it from private to public.

Comment: @user1899933: he told you that you need to create a getter method, not change the visibility status of the variable itself.

Comment: Hovercraft is spot on, but I'll ask another question: Who's writing this code?  You or NetBeans?  It's just an IDE.  I'm not saying that you should make it public, but it sounds to me like you depend far too much on an IDE without understanding how these things work.

Comment: Thanx for the help. Im just a beginner. I'm trying on some stuff knowing only the basics of java. Thats why i'm depending on the IDE. Still i'munable to write a code my self without a IDE.

BTW i solved this problem by changing Private >>> public static using the notepad(not in IDE).

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to use `dp_1` outside the class in which it is defined.

SO the solution is to either increase its visibility by modifying access level to either default, protected or public

Or create a public method that returns `dp_1` object from it and then access it.